# Mysqli Update UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, when I update stuff in my database it turns for example this: `Š` to this: `u0160` it would be ok if it turned into this: `\u0160` so it would display right but it doesn’t.

This is my connection file:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
mysqli_query("set names utf8");
?>
```

And this is the query:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE schools SET subjectData='$json' WHERE id='$schoolID'");
```

- **Value of `$json`:** `{"subject":"A","desc":"A\u017d"}`
- **Value of db entry:** `{"subject":"A","desc":"Au017d"}`

Comment: shownplease your table charset declaration? and value of your `$json` variable? and the code where you try to output values from databasE?

Comment: Is this really in your db or just when you output it?Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you showed the variable value, but you didn't show the code where you extract values from database.

And another note : your value is not really utf8, 
it is json encoded string:

```
{"subject":"A","desc":"A\u017d"}
```

As you see, the original string is not equal to value stored in database:

```
{"subject":"A","desc":"Au017d"}
```

Saving raw json in database is not very best practice. I would suggest to save just values not objects.

But if you need this, you should use this when you insert and/or update records:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE schools SET subjectData='".mysqli_escape_string($json)."' WHERE id='$schoolID'");
```

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8 at all, you're only handling pure ASCII values. Your issue is that a backslash, a necessary part of the JSON encoding, is disappearing as you enter it into the database. The reason for that would be that you're not escaping your data correctly. A backslash has a special escaping meaning in SQL, if you want to insert a literal backslash into the database it requires escaping. With mysqli, you should be using prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE schools SET subjectData = ? WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $json, $schoolID);
$stmt->execute();
```

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/476) and [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: you just missed `$` dollar sign in `$schoolID`

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I am using mysqli procedural!